# accessing parent directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I get the parent directory of the following directory?

```
string rootFolder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(APP_PATH);
```

Comment: You mean the parent physical folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new DirectoryInfo(rootFolder).Parent.FullName` or `Directory.GetParent(rootFolder).FullName`

Comment: For some reason, GetParent gives me the exact same folder

Comment: This is what got me the folder I wanted : string str = Directory.GetParent(rootFolder).Parent.FullName;

Comment: In that case you could just use `new DirectoryInfo(rootFolder).Parent.FullName` for readability.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Directory.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx).